# About application of Hahn-Banach

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let assume that $\Phi$ is a convex and lower semicontinuous functional on $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$. By Hahn-Banach theorem, it is well known that $\Phi$ is the supremum of a family of linear functionals in $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$. But how to show that given a $\delta>0$ and a nonnegative function $\psi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with $\psi \geq 1$ in the compact set $K \subset \Omega$ there exists a continuous linear functional $F\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that

$$ \Phi(\psi) \leq F(\psi)+ \delta.$$

Comment: Take $F$ such that $F(\psi)\ne0$ then multiply $F$ by a suitable constant.